# How to count the number of occurrences in a self-referencing column?

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregate-functions

I am new to SQL and I've been struggling with this example for quite a while now.

I have this table:
[image: database table]

So, what is asked from me is to produce a count of the number of recommendations each member has made. Order by number of recommendations. The final result should look something like this:
[image: final result]

I really am confused, since the values of column `recommendedby` is actually the `id` of the member. I don't know how to "recognize" them as `id` and not just some values, count how many recommendations each member has and "connect" them to `memid` column to get to needed result.

So far I managed to do this:

```
SELECT COUNT(recommendedby)
FROM members
GROUP BY recommendedby
```

But I'm stuck now. I get a counted number of recommendations for each `id`, but it's not connected to actual `id`. This is my result.

[image: my result]

Comment: `select recommendedby as id, count('Dracula') as cnt from members group by recommendedby`

Comment: Please post character data like code as **text**, never as image. Provide your Postgres version, proper table definitions and [a minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you're looking for:

```
select "id"
     , (select count(1) 
          from "members" 
         where "recommendedby" = m."id") 
  from "members" m
```

Although using subqueries are not very popular and can cause serious performance issues, this is imho the easiest way to learn what you're doing.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a self-join for this:

```
SELECT m.id,
       count(r.id) AS recommendations
FROM members AS m
   LEFT JOIN members AS r
      ON r.recommendedby = m.id
GROUP BY m.id
ORDER BY recommendations;
```

The left join will make `r.id` be NULL for members that made no recommendation, and `count` won't count such NULL values.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways you can go with.

1. Join + Group By

This is pretty simple, all you need to do is put the query you made as SubQuery and Join your table with that.

```sql
SELECT members.*, rec.recommendations
FROM members
 LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT COUNT(recommendedby) recommendations, recommendedby
   FROM members
   GROUP BY recommendedby
 ) rec ON rec.recommendedby = members.id
```

2. Lateral

```sql
SELECT m1.*, rec.recommendations
FROM members m1,
LATERAL (
 SELECT COUNT(recommendedby) recommendations
   FROM members m2
   WHERE m1.id = m2.id
)
```

Hope this can help.